# PHP - Parsing String As Past Date

Tags: php, date, strtotime

Currently, I'm trying to parse out dates when messages were received into timestamps. I have the month and day but the year is not specified. The event always occurs at the most recent (human) reading of the time. It works great in most cases to do this:

```
$time = strtotime("Jan 2 8:38pm");
```

That returns a date for this year, which is correct. Unfortunately, I get problems when I try to do for example:

```
$time = strtotime("Dec 31 8:38pm");
```

That returns a date which hasn't happened yet, and wont happen for the whole rest of the year. Obviously, my message was not sent in the future. I need it to return December 31st of last year.

For weekdays, I had a solution by prepending 'last' before the weekday like so:

```
$time = strtotime("Last Saturday 8:38pm");
```

That always returned the time of the last Saturday. However, trying to do the same thing here doesn't work:

```
$time = strtotime("Last Dec 31 8:38pm");
```

This returns false. I know to decrement a date by 1 year, I can do this:

```
$time = strtotime("Dec 31 8:38pm -1 year");
```

And that works great for Dec 31. However, Jan 2 will now fail:

```
$time = strtotime("Jan 2 8:38pm -1 year");
```

One solution I thought of was to subtract off a year (86400 * 365) from the resulting value if it is past today's date. However, this result will fail if we passed over February of a leap year. In that case, we would end up with a time that was ahead by a day.

The best solution I came up with so far is this:

```
$time = strtotime($raw_time);
if ($time > time()) {
  $time = strtotime($raw_time." -1 year");
}
```

It seems kind of wasteful to make two calls to strtotime which I know is probably not a very efficient function. Is this the most elegant solution?

Is anyone aware of an option in strtotime which forces the dates to be in the past instead of in the future?

Is there another way to parse these dates that I should consider?

Efficiency is important for this because I am going to be parsing a lot of dates with it, but I would also like simple and readable code so I can understand it later.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php chk examples

Comment: You don't need to parse the same string twice. `strtotime('-1 year', $time)` will do the same.

Comment: I've looked at that page a lot. That was the first place I looked. I was kind of expecting there would be a simple option. Maybe I overlooked it. I did a specific search for 'last' and 'previous' on the page and I can't find anything still. I've also Googled things like 'strtotime date in past' and had no luck that way.

Comment: For strtotime('-1 year', $time), the $time is the raw string? As far as I can tell, the second parameter to strtotime has to be an integer. If you are suggesting $time = strtotime($raw_time); if ($time > time()) $time = strtotime("-1 year", $time); that's probably faster though there are still two strtotime calls.

Comment: can you make a fix date format so that you can split it and pass to strtotime, will it possible for you, that will be very helpful for you

Comment: Yes I've done that. In fact, I already do the parsing to ensure the format matches what I expect. But how can I get strtotime to interpret this properly as the last time this date occurred instead of the date this year?

Comment: I meant `strtotime('-1 year', $time)` exactly in the context of your code, where `$time = strtotime($raw_time);`. I'm not saying it's faster or slower, I just meant that you don't need to parse `"Dec 31 8:38pm"` twice if you don't want to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is fine, as there is no date format to get what you want. Another approach could be using the `DateTime` class:

```
$datetime = new DateTime($raw_time);
if ($datetime > new DateTime()) {
    $datetime->modify('-1 year');
}
```

You could test which one of the two approaches is faster. My guess is that this is a micro-optimization that won't make a lot of difference.